# why have to use [i + j] and j+1 in the if-statements?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand code solution to Find the Index of the First Occurrence in a String problem. I found this code online but I can quite wrap my head over the two ifs statements lines:
if (needle[j] !== haystack[i + j]) break;
if (j + 1 === needle.length)
can someone break it down for please?

```
let strStr = (haystack, needle) => {
    // we loop through the first string 
    for (let i = 0; i < haystack.length; i++) {
        // we loop through the second string
        for (let j = 0; j < needle.length; j++) {
            if (needle[j] !== haystack[i + j]) break;
            if (j + 1 === needle.length) {
                return i
            }
        }
    }
    return -1
};
strStr('sadbutsad', 'sad')
```

Comment: draw it on paper. `i` is functioning as an offset to which we can apply `j` in order to move the starting position in the search for `needle`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to understand what your code does, you first need to understand the `break` statement: `break` will exit the *closest/nearest* loop, i.e. the most indented one:

```js
for (let a ...) { // for A
    for (let b ...) {  // for B
        break; // this will break for B
    }
    // after the break, the code execution will resume here
    console.log("more code here...")
}
```

Now, for your code. The 2 `for` statements iterate character by character, through the 2 strings: *haystack* and *needle*. Let's give these strings some values, to better explain:

- haystack = "hello world!!!"
- needle   = "world"

The first for (which uses the `i` variable), goes through the *haystack*, character by character. For each index `i`, it tries to match the *needle* string with some part of the *haystack* string, starting at index i:

- i = 0:

```
          0123456789... (haystack indices)
haystack: hello world!!!
          ^i=0

needle:   world
          01234  (needle indices)
```

- i = 1:

```
          0123456789... (haystack indices)
haystack: hello world!!!
           ^i=1

needle:    world
           01234  (needle indices)
```

- i = 2:

```
          0123456789... (haystack indices)
haystack: hello world!!!
            ^i=2

needle:     world
            01234  (needle indices)
```

- and so on... until i = 6:

```
          0123456789... (haystack indices)
haystack: hello world!!!
                ^i=6

needle:         world
                01234  (needle indices)
```

The second `for` actually compares the aligned portions of the string for equality, character by character, this time going character by character through the *needle* string. First, we need to compare the character at index 6 in *haystack* (the 'w') with the character at index 0 in *needle* (also the 'w'):

```
          0123456789... (haystack indices)
haystack: hello world!!!
                ^i=6

needle:         world
                01234  (needle indices)
                ^j=0
```

If this equality fails, we stop the entire comparison (which is the second for, the one using the `j` variable, using the `break` statement). Next, we do this again for j=1:

```
          0123456789... (haystack indices)
haystack: hello world!!!
                ^i=6

needle:         world
                01234  (needle indices)
                 ^j=1
```

Now, we need to compare the 2 'o's (at indices **7** and **1** in the 2 strings, respectively). To get the **7**, we add `i + j`, and to get the **1**, we just use `j`. Finally, if we check all the characters and they all match, we want to report the 'succes' (which we do by returning the index `i` in the *haystack* at which we matched the *needle*). We know that we finished checking all the characters if we reach the last character, which is `needle.length - 1` (because length 5 means indices 0-4; last index is 4 = 5-1). This is what the `if` checks - if we reached the last character. If we do, it means that the `break` statement was never executed, so there wasn't a single character that didn't match.

Comment: That's a good, clear explanation!

Answer (score 2):

So what this code is actually *doing* is looking at the string `haystack` and returning the character index of the beginning of the substring `needle` inside `haystack`, if any.

`if (needle[j] !== haystack[i + j]) break;`
In context, `i` is the beginning of the substring of haystack currently being tested to see if it is the same thing as needle.   The inner loop, `j`, is checking each character of both needle and haystack to see if they're the same thing.   "needle" always starts at zero, because you're looking at that whole string, so you use `needle[j]`.  "haystack" starts at `i` because of the outer loop, so it uses `haystack[i+j]`.   If those characters don't match, then your inner loop knows it's found something that isn't the same as needle, so breaks and goes on to the next iteration of the outer loop.

`if (j + 1 === needle.length) return i` is easier to explain:  if needle is three characters long, you only need to check three characters, and since they all match (which we know because the earlier condition didn't `break`) then we know we've found the needle in the haystack, and can return its initial index.

(This is, strictly speaking, unnecessary, because the inner loop I about to end at that point anyway (because `j` iterates only up to `needle.length`).   So instead of that `if`statement, you could simply `return i` after the inner loop: if you reach that point without breaking, you know you have a full match.

I suspect that that line was included just to make it more explicit, and easier to understand the code in a teaching context.  Personally I sometimes include "unnecessary" code like that intentionally, if it makes the function easier to understand at a glance, though in this case a code comment would serve as well.)

```js
let strStr = (haystack, needle) => {
    // we loop through the first string 
    for (let i = 0; i < haystack.length; i++) {
        // we loop through the second string
        for (let j = 0; j < needle.length; j++) {
            // if the "j"th character of needle is not the same as the "j"th character of haystack starting at i:
            if (needle[j] !== haystack[i + j]) break;
            
            // have we run out of needle to test?
            if (j + 1 === needle.length) {
                return i
            }
        }
        // (or we could just `return i` here instead of the "have we run out of needle" conditional above)
    }
    // if we made it here, we got all the way through the haystack without finding a needle, so indicate failure:
    return -1
};
console.log(strStr('sadbutsad', 'sad'))
```

Your given example has the result being 0, but it'll be a little better to explain if it's not as simple a case.  Let's say "haystack" contains "xyzababcdxyz", and "needle" is "abcd".

`i` will start at 0, `j` will start at 0, `needle[j]` is "a" and `haystack[i+j]` is "x".  Those are unequal so will break; same thing for i=1 and i=2.

At `i=3` things get more interesting.

The inner loop starts at zero again.   `needle[j]` is `needle[0]` is "a".  `haystack[i+j]` is `haystack[3+0]` is "a".  That matches, so we go on to i=3,j=1, and get `needle[1]` and `haystack[4]`, which again match ("b").   So we go on to i=3,j=2, which is `needle[2]` compared to `haystack[5]`, but those don't match ("c" and "a"). So we break out of the inner loop again, and increment `i` again.

i=4, j=0 doesn't match, so we break immediately.

At i=5, we start to see matches again, and this time make it all the way through the full length of `needle` without finding a mismatch, so we know we can return `i` as the output.

Comment: "`if (j + 1 === needle.length) return i` is *easier to explain*" - for unexplainable check that essentially repeats the iteration condition :) ... Obviously we don't need to suggest to use more sensible code... but maybe one should look for code that at least uses semicolons consistently.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I added a bit more commentary about that line.  You're right that strictly speaking it's unnecessary, but I have to assume this code was used in a teaching context, and that line makes it more  immediately obvious what's happening.

Comment: And semicolons, schmemicolons, as long as it works :)